# How to connect my flutter app to remotemsql.com database

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, remote-mysql

I am working on a flutter app that needs to connect with a remote mysql db on remotemysql.com. I have created the db and tables on remotemysql.com but I don't know how to connect the flutter app with the db. I read some tutorials on how to do this but I noticed that they usually upload some php files on the server. The file(s) will contain script that makes connection to the db or do any of the CRUD operations. After uploading this file(s) then the url generated is what's used in the app to connect the app with the remote db. I want to know how this can be done with remotemysql.com if it can be done and if it can't be done then how can I get my flutter app to connect with mysql db on remotemysql.com?

Please note: I don't know anything about phpmyadmin